# Laravel Mail::send() illegal offet 'name'

Tags: php, email, laravel, sendmail, mail-sender

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I am having trouble with an error for "illegal string offset" when processing form input for use with the Laravel Mail::send().

This is the code which processes the form input, as it has to be an array.

```
$msg = array(
    'name'=>Input::get('name'),
    'email'=>Input::get('email'),
    'message'=>Input::get('message')
);
```

Then I try to send it through Mail::send().

```
Mail::send('emails.question', $msg, function($message) {
    $message->to('myPersonalEmail@domain.com')->subject('Email from your website!');
});
```

The app/views/emails/question.blade.php template is extremely simple.

```
{{ $msg['name'] }} <br/>
{{ $msg['email'] }} <br/>
{{ $msg['message'] }}
```

Yet I still get the following error.

```
    ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Illegal string offset 'name' (View:
[intentionally omitted for privacy]/app/views/emails/question.blade.php)
```

I believe the error is referring to the $msg['name'] not being present, but if I return the view instead I do not receive an error at all.

```
return View::make('emails.questions')->with('msg',$msg);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed `$msg` as an associative array, so the items of `$msg` array are available to the view by `$key`. That's mean in your case like `$name`, `$email` and so on. The app/views/emails/question.blade.php now will be like this

```
{{ $name }} <br/>
{{ $email }} <br/>
{{ $message }}
```